# Terraform module structure to handle incremental azure vdi

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I am currently using Terraform to create Azure vdi.
My current structure is

```
main.tf
input.tf
module/ main.tf, var.tf
```

So whenever a user joined the particular team, I do the following steps
Let say user1

```
Currently I am creating user1 folder with input.tf file and create the resource, Similar when user2 comes I am doing the same process (folder user2).
```

Is there any better way to handle such requirement  ??

Comment: vid for user2 will override vdi for user 1. Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: Yeah, how to handle it ?

Comment: What is the module for? A module represents VDI?

Comment: Yes, Module container main code to create vdi.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to do that:

1. Separate config files and folders - you are already doing this, and as the number of users increases, it will be a problem. But it is also most flexible, as you can custom modify TF files for each user separately.
2. Use a `set` of users as an input. So you have one folder and one copy of your TF code, but you maintain `set` variable with users. Then use `for_each` to create different instance of `module` for each user. For example:

```
variable "users" {
  type = set(string)       
  default = ["user1", "user2"]
}

module "vdi" {
  source = "./module"

  for_each = var.users
}
```

3. Use a separate [workspace](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces) for each user.